# I am trying to add paytmallinone sdk in my react-native project after installing package and doing pod install, I am getting error

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, paytm

Multiple commands produce '/Users/apexwebapex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jobxrobot-gdfmrwwktmysylcicpnsfjsvumtp/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/paytm_allinone_react-native/paytm_allinone_react_native.framework/Headers/AppInvokeSDK-Swift.h'

I have checked the instruction in paytm site and followed the same instruction ,still getting issue if I run pod install and then run react-native run-ios --device .

I was expecting my app to run normally after pod install but it showing this error.